# Is there an opposite of catch?

Tags: javascript, node.js

By running the following, you can run code if an error is thrown.

```
try {
    // test
} catch (e) {
    // error output
}
```

Is there a similar way to run code only if **no** error is thrown?

Comment: You can set a flag in the `catch` and then check it after.

Comment: I would recommend checking the docs at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch to get an understanding on how the try/catch/finally clauses works.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sure there is, see the comment inline.

```
try {
// test
// No error is thrown if program control reaches here
} catch {
// error output
}
```

Consider using an additional `try` block in the "No error is thrown" part if you don't want the outer `catch` to handle any other errors.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer assumes that there is no return statements in the try block, which wasn't my case. In my case, there was multiple early return statements, and I wanted to run code as long as there wasn't an error. In that case you have a few options:

Using finally and a boolean to see if you got an error:

```js
function check () {
    let allGood = true;
    try {
        if (condition1()) {
            return 'foo';
        }

        if (condition2()) {
            return 'bar';
        }

        return doit();
    } catch (e) {
        allGood = false;
        console.error('Oh no!', e);
        return 'bad';
    } finally {
        if (allGood) {
            console.log('All good');
        }
    }
}
```

This is pretty straightforward, preserves your return value and allows you do more complex error handling in the catch, so you could conditional set allGood whether you could recover from the error or not.

If your catch instead rethrows the error, you could use an [immediately invoked function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE):

```js
function check () {
    const result = (() => {
        try {
            if (condition1()) {
                return 'foo';
            }

            if (condition2()) {
                return 'bar';
            }

            return doit();
        } catch (e) {
            console.error('Oh no!', e);
            throw e;
        }
    })();

    console.log('All good. Also I have access to', result);
    return result;
}
```

Errors will bubble out and not run the console.log at the bottom. It becomes even more succinct if you don't need a return value or catch:

```
function check () {
    (() => {
        if (condition1()) {
            return;
        }

        if (condition2()) {
            return;
        }

        doit();
    })();

    console.log('All good. No errors.');
}
```

Depending on what your function is throwing or returning, single or early returning, and how you want to handle the good/bad state, there's quite a few ways to handle it. You just have to pick what fits your code the best.